# How to use COWIN api's to intimate me when slots are available, preferred on mac

Tags: python, json

How to use COWIN api's to intimate me when slots are available, preferred on mac or windows also fine.

Comment: ΩHi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use below Sample code and modify according to your preferred Date and District Id

Use below link to find the state_id's
https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states

Use below link to find the district_Id's
https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/districts/16

For example, If I am looking for Bangalore Urban,
My District Code would be 265

If you are looking for developing a generic app/code you can query the above api's and match the desired District number with your district of choice to get the district Id.

Rest of sample code is as follows:

```
import urllib.request as request
import json
import os
from time import sleep
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}

#Config
min_age = 45
district1 = "294"
date1 ="11-05-2021"

district2 = "265"
date2 ="11-05-2021"

reg_url_1 = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id="+ district1 +"&date=" + date1
reg_url_2 = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id="+ district2 +"&date=" + date2
req1 = Request(url=reg_url_1, headers=headers)
req2 = Request(url=reg_url_2, headers=headers)
os.system('say "Starting Script"')

def cowin_check_slots():
    sleep(3);
    with request.urlopen(req1) as response:
        if response.getcode() == 200:
            source = response.read()
            data = json.loads(source)
            lst = data['sessions']
            for i in lst:
                age = i['min_age_limit']
                if age == min_age :
                    print("success")
                    print(i['name'])
                    print(i['pincode'])
                    os.system('say "Akshay, Slots are available now"')
                    print(i['district_name'])

        else:
            print('An error occurred while attempting to retrieve data from the API.')
    sleep(3);
    with request.urlopen(req2) as response:
        if response.getcode() == 200:
            source = response.read()
            data = json.loads(source)
            lst = data['sessions']
            for i in lst:
                age = i['min_age_limit']
                if age == min_age :
                    os.system('say "Akshay, Slots are available now"')
                    print("success")
                    print(i['name'])
                    print(i['pincode'])
                    print(i['district_name'])

        else:
            print('An error occurred while attempting to retrieve data from the API.')

while(1):
    cowin_check_slots()
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no free options for it but you can change the code and make a use  of proxies available for free thats the only option you can do if you want to host in heroku or cloud services (I am talking when the cloud hoster is out of India so that it cannot reach it and probably there are no free proxies for Indian Region so )